# Error in Copy one node with its children in Treeview to another treeview

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms, treeview

I am creating a new treeview and then want to copy some of other nodes to it.
But I have the following error:

> Cannot add or insert the item '' in more than one place. You
>   must first remove it from its current location or clone it.

My code is as:

```
first_treeview.Nodes.Clear();
//treeView2.Nodes.Clear();
int length_last = treeview1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Count;
for (int ii = 0; ii < length_last - 1; ii++)
{
    TreeNode temp_node = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[ii];
    first_treeview.Nodes.Add(temp_node);
}
```

and the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<component version="11">
<config />
<protect>
    <this>
        <user ="Mike"/>
    </this>
</protect>  
<actions>
    <action name="test">
        <obj name="system">             
        </obj>
    </action>
</actions>
</component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that one node cannot belong to 2 treeviews. So you have to clone it before adding it to `first_treeview`.

```
first_treeview.Nodes.Add((TreeNode) temp_node.Clone());
```